# adding JFrame background caused .JAR to be broken

Tags: java, jframe

I want to know what is the problem in my code that caused .JAR file to be broken? when I double click on jar file it doesn't open but it was fine before adding background image to JFrame.

I created a class called Cube to draw cube and I want to set background image to JFrame, so I added field in Cube class

```
private BufferedImage bg;
```

bg initialization in the class constructor

```
publice Cube() {
bg = ImageIO.read(new File("bg_image.jpg"));
}
```

this piece of code used to set the background

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
}
```

in main class I created JFrame object to draw the cube

```
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.add(new Cube());
    jf.setEnabled(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    jf.setResizable(false);
    jf.setSize( 500, 500 );
    jf.setVisible( true );
```

Comment: The problem is probably in opening the image. When you compile your project, the image is loaded locally (in the project folder), but when you export to .jar, the image is probably not in the same folder as the jar, thus it throws an exception because the image can't be found. Since you have no exception control, the exception will kill the app.

Comment: `when I double click on jar file it doesn't open` Run the jar from the command line so you can see any Exceptions that might be thrown - most probably occurs when loading that image.

Comment: thanks mush it is really working now after adding the image in the same folder of jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not have your jar file there is no way for me to know the problem.  You need to access the file as a resource and not as a new file because it is inside the jar.  First you should use cmd to run the jar and see if it gives you a stack trace. Use the command: `java -jar filename.jar` to run the jar via command prompt.

Try using:

```
Cube.class.getResourceAsStream("bg_image.jpg");
```

Comment: it is solved after adding the image in the same folder of jar file, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> bg = ImageIO.read(new File("bg_image.jpg"));

This code says that `bg_image.jpg` should be near with .jar

You may put image into resources and load it like:

```
Cube.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bg_image.jpg");
```

ps: load resources in constructor is bad idea!